# If $a,b,c$ are positive, then $(a+b+c)(1/a+1/b+1/c)\ge 9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, means

The question asks to prove that if  "$x_1,x_2,x_3$ are positive numbers show that:
$$(x_1+x_2+x_3) \left(\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}+\frac{1}{x_3} \right)\ge 9$$

I've tried to use the fact that the arithmetic mean is greater than the harmonic mean since it looks like it's kind of in that form but it doesn't seem to work. I tried expanding it too and simplifying a little to get:
$$ x_1^2(x_2+x_3)+x_2^2(x_1+x_3)+x_3^2(x_1+x_2)\ge 6 x_1x_2x_3$$

but I can't seem to see anyway to further get it into a form that easily proves the required inequality. Any hints as to a way to do this?

Comment: Use AM-GM, AM-HM or tchebychef's inequality

Comment: It is actually the AM-HM part of AM-GM-HM, and as a part of RMS-AM-GM-HM...

Comment: Direct by Cauchy Schwarz...

Comment: @Macavity how might you do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Arithmetic-harmonic mean inequality is actually the usual way of doing this.

We have $ \frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}\geq \frac{n}{\frac{1}{x_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_n}} $ in general. Write it out for $n=3$, and stare at it for a bit - it's a very simple manipulation.

Comment: I see what I've done now, I for some reason thought that the harmonic mean was $\frac{1}{n}\sum \frac{1}{x_i}$ and not the reciprocal. It's completely obvious and ridiculously easy now when its't the right way round! Thanks

Comment: @Jay I thought maybe you'd done that!

Comment: @Jay if the answer was helpful, accepting it is a useful way of marking that for others viewing the topic

Comment: yeah, I'm trying too but it isn't letting me until there's been a certain amount of time, I don't remember there being a minimum time before you could accept an answer to a question but I suppose it makes some sense.

Comment: It does make sense, no worries.

Answer (score 5):

Let $u=\langle\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b},\sqrt{c}\rangle$ and $v=\langle\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}\rangle$.

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,

$(u\cdot v)^2\le|u|^2|v|^2$ so $\displaystyle9\le(a+b+c)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)$.

Answer (score 3):

You use the Cauchy inequality, $x+y+z\ge 3\sqrt[3]{xyz}$ for all $x,y,z\ge 0$, to prove the statement.
Solve: We have
$$a+b+c\ge 3\sqrt[3]{abc},$$
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\ge 3\sqrt[3]{{\frac{1}{a}.\frac{1}{b}.\frac{1}{c}}} = \frac{3}{{\sqrt[3]{{abc}}}}.$$
So, we have
$$\left( {a + b + c} \right)\left( {\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}} \right) \geqslant 3\sqrt[3]{{abc}}.\frac{3}{{\sqrt[3]{{abc}}}} = 9.$$
The inequality is proved.

Comment: I was just thinking how to use the Cauchy inequality to do this. Thanks!

Comment: actually isn't that the AM-GM inequality again? Isn't [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Schwarz_inequality) the Cauchy Inequality. Even so it's still a nice way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

As $x\to 1/x$ is convex on $(0,\infty)$:

$$
1/\left[
\frac 13 \left(
x+y+z\right)\right]
\le 
\frac 13 \left(
1/x+1/y+1/z\right)
\\
1\le 
\frac 13 \left(
1/x+1/y+1/z\right)\frac 13 \left(
x+y+z\right)
\\
9\le 
\left(
1/x+1/y+1/z\right)\left(
x+y+z\right)
$$